# Is Yi (yee) a proper/accepted way of stating the number 2?

Tags: pronunciation

In my taekwondo class the instructors tend to pronounce the Sino-Korean version of the number 2 as Yi or "yee" - as opposed to "ee" (이). Is this correct and, if so, how is this written in Hangul?

--- Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Koreans have the syllable "이" which is pronounced like saying the letter "e".

> [English Long E sound /i/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgX6cakDwB0)

However the romanization of this is quite a challenge.  We've seen (in names)

> Lee, Yi, Ree, Rhee (and etc).

My guess is that the instructors saw the sino-korean numbers romanized and are thusly pronouncing it as seen in romanized sino-korean "Yi"; however, this is not the correct pronunciation.  See the [youtube video on English Long E sound /i/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgX6cakDwB0) because it is nearly identical.

And as you stated in the question, the correct hangul for the sino-korean number two is

> 이

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! While I can't read/speak Korean fluently (yet), my son and I have taken Korean (Hangul) lessons off and on for a while now and I couldn't understand how this was correct. I agree that they are likely using the romanized (is that a word?) pronunciation.

Comment: Yes, romanization is (according to wiki): _(also spelled romanisation), in linguistics, is the conversion of writing from a different writing system to the Roman (Latin) script, or a system for doing so._ I think the instructors still should get an A for effort, though :) and we can pronounce it _Yay_ just to fit in.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not knocking the instructors! Just looking for the correct pronunciation since we count a lot in class (using native Korean numbers as well as Sino-Korean numbers). Thanks again!